# base64 decode with openssl BIO block by block

Tags: c++, encoding, openssl, base64

I have a problem with decoding base64-encoded data with the following code. I have about 3.5 MB of data to decode. It works almost fine until the very end where something is missing.

The following code reads 100 kB source data block, writes it to BIO_s_mem, then reads decoded data by 1024 bytes multiple times. When there is nothing more to read, another 100 kB block is retrieved and used again. It goes fine until the last block is received. It has not full 100 kB (only 25685 bytes). I write it to BIO, get 18 times decoded 1024 bytes, then another 435 and that's it. But it is not all. About 100 bytes of decoded data is still missing to be read.

All encoded data are correctly received (saving them to file and decoding manually from shell command gives full output). How should I get the rest from the BIO? I guess I should somehow say that it is all. I tried for example BIO_flush multiple ways, some flags, addding newline to encoded data, no success yet.

```
BIO *bmem, *b64;
b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_push(b64, bmem);
vector<char> buf(1024);

while (!end) {
    end = task->nextChunk(chunk, chunkSize); // this reads encoded data block
    BIO_write(bmem, (void*)chunk, chunkSize);
    cout << "Chunk size: " << chunkSize << endl;
    if (end || chunkSize == 0) {
        BIO_flush(bmem); // I tried multiple things
        BIO_flush(b64); // flush here and there, nothing helped
        BIO_set_close(bmem, BIO_CLOSE); // and other things... ;-)
    }

    string result;
    int nread;
    while ((nread = BIO_read(b64, buf.data(), buf.size())) > 0) {
        cout << "Decoded bytes read: " << nread << endl;
        result.append(buf.data(), nread);
    }
    ret->appendRaw(result.c_str(), result.size()); // store result somehow
}
```

Last output sequence:

```
Chunk size: 25685
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 1024
Decoded bytes read: 435
Chunk size: 0
```

So once again: the decoded output is binary file. It is correctly encoded, correctly sent to my code, but not decoded, last about 100 bytes is missing.
Thank you for any hints.

Comment: I *think* `(nread = BIO_read(b64, buf.data(), buf.size())) > 0` may not be quite right. I think the test to perform on a bio is `do { len = BIO_read(b64, ...); } while (len > 0 || BIO_should_retry(b64));` But that's for a socket bio; I'm not sure how a file or memory bio differs.

Comment: Thank you for a hint. I already experimented with this. When all chunks are written to my BIO_s_mem then reading from b64 gives -1 and BIO_should_retry(b64) stays true, so it never ends. That's why I thought I need to say somehow "that's all" and the last part will be decoded, returned and the loop can finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was in adding following two lines before the final BIO_read sequence:

```
        BIO_write(bmem, "\n", 1);
        BIO_set_mem_eof_return(bmem, BIO_NOCLOSE);
```